# how to display post tag alphabetically in search form dropdown?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, search, tags

Using search and filter pro form to sort post with tags, categories and other short orders. Want to display tags in dropdown alphabetically.  [tags dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XezCo.png)

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

Installed this plugins and allowed me to change order of tags in wp-admin area. https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/